# How to position an image in OpenLayers 3 map?

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a png image of other map that I know the original bounding box and the original projection. This image is 400x400 large but I have control over its width and height and can generate any size I want.

How can I position this image over my OL map in the correct location?

Both have same SRID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry guys. I need to learn to search a little more before ask.

```
        var imageLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
            source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/mclm/img/export.png',
                projection: 'EPSG:4326',
                imageExtent: [-44,-23,-42,-21]  
            })
        });
```